# How to add image to row action in Table View?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableviewrowaction

How to add custom image to delete button when swiping cell from right on `UITableview` as shown in the below image?

[image]

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let remove = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "\nRemove") { action, indexPath in }
    remove.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "remove")!) }
```

From the above code, Image is showing but, it is showing as a group of images stacked together. I mean, I am unable to set the `"ContentMode"` to `".ScaleToAspectFit"` for the `"UIImage"`

What is the best way for this approach?

sample code could be appreciable.

Comment: https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell should be helpful

Comment: Answered here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771778/how-to-add-image-in-uitableviewrowaction/45301272#45301272

Answer (score 6):

Inspired with Denny's answer. Here is objective-c version of his code.

```
- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewRowAction *deleteAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"           " handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Do you really want to delete this comment?" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];

        [alertView setTag:101];
        [alertView show];
    }];

    UITableViewCell *commentCell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGFloat height = commentCell.frame.size.height;

    UIImage *backgroundImage = [self deleteImageForHeight:height];

    deleteAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];

    return @[deleteAction];
}
```

And below is the image drawing method:

```
- (UIImage*)deleteImageForHeight:(CGFloat)height{

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 62, height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(62, height), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, frame);

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-delete"];

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(frame.size.width/2.0, frame.size.height/2.0 - 10, 18, 20)];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

And the result is:
[image: Table view cell delete image]

Comment: Brilliant solution! I just want to mention, that  `title:@"           "` is important only for iOS < 11.0

Comment: @VladE.Borovtsov I write this for iOS8 and not sure about latest version. Thank you for the updates.

Comment: @Muzamill, it works fine even on iOS 12. On iOS 11 and iOS 12 the action buttons appears squared with `title=nil` or `title=@""`. But on lower version, to keep  button squared and looking similar i had to insert title with 8 spaces.

Comment: @VladE.Borovtsov Great Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Essentially, you are drawing in a context, then retrieve the new image from the context.

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 100))
label.text = "ADD"
label.textAlignment = .Center
label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let img: UIImage = UIImage(named: "delete")

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgSize, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

// Set background color
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.raangeRed().CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80))

// Draw image
img.drawInRect(CGRectMake(30, 15, 20, 20))

// Draw View
label.layer.renderInContext(context!)

// Retrieve new UIImage
let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

let deleteRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "           ") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
     // Do stuff   
    }
deleteRowAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: newImage)
```

You can also create a custom view (with an UIImageView and UILabel) and render it inside the context.

Comment: Wow, great example! Thanks for showing how to use CGContext to draw label and apply background colour! Just what i needed

Comment: Though the label seems slightly 'blurred' and does not give a nice visual. It would definitely work better if the image contains the text as well.

Comment: Exactly, depending also with your designer, if both of you can agree if the buttons will be dynamic or not

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
let backImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "remove"))
backImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
remove.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage:backImage.image!)
```

**Choice-2**

```
var img: UIImage = UIImage(named: "remove")
var imgSize: CGSize = tableView.frame.size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgSize)
img.drawInRect(CGRectMake(20, 0, 20, 20))
var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
remove.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: newImage)
```

Comment: Thanks Anbu. I've already tried first approach, but no use. Now, while trying second approach it is showing error `Value of type "UITableViewRowAction" has no member "frame"`. I understood that we need to give the action's height and width.

Comment: we cannot use `tableView` height, as it is much bigger than row right?

Comment: @kumar - ok choice no 2 is works correct, if yes we go for next step

Comment: Choice 2 works, but with custom `CGRectMake(20,0,20,20)`

Comment: @kumar -- happy to hear ,your problem is resolved or not

Comment: One more thing, I cannot set the background custom color and cannot set multiple actions with image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108508/discussion-between-kumar-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: @ThreeCoins  there is only image but no title text and no background color. how to achieve this all (image + text + background color)? swift 3

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 Xcode 11.3
Only Copy and Paste Code.....

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (action, view, completion) in
        completion(true)
        print("Delete")
    }
    
    let muteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Save") { (action, view, completion) in
        completion(true)
        print("Save")
    }
    
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "dustbin")
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    
    muteAction.image = UIImage(named: "file")
    muteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, muteAction])
}
```

[image]