# Setting editActionsForRowAt action backgroundColor with patternImage swift 3

Tags: swift, uiimage, tableview, action

I have this problem when setting backgroundColor with patternImage with swift 3 in tableView actionsForRow..
[image]

my code:

```
 delete.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: (UIImage(named: "button-delete-default-png")!))
```

Any ideas? I've been searching about two days, and nothing..

Thanks in advance to any suggest!

Comment: This worked for me!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36472413/1786069